# PHP / MYSQL: Database empties when I use a variable in the WHERE condition of the last mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$search = $_POST["search"];
```

These two queries work fine. So I used their format for the one below.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE $search = `student_id`");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `grades` WHERE $search = `student_id`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
echo"<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo    "<th>Subjects:</th>";
echo    "<th>Current Mark:</th>";
echo    "<th>Edit Mark:</th>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['c1'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m1'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m1'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c2'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m2'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m2'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c3'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m3'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m3'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c4'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m4'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m4'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c5'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m5'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m5'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c6'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m6'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m6'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>". $row['c7'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row2['m7'] ."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='m7'></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
}

 $M1 = $_POST["m1"];
 $M2 = $_POST["m2"];
 $M3 = $_POST["m3"];
 $M4 = $_POST["m4"];
 $M5 = $_POST["m5"];
 $M6 = $_POST["m6"];
 $M7 = $_POST["m7"];
```

It works if I put numbers e.x. 11111

Otherwise it just enters blank spaces into the table.

I've tried '".$search."'

I've tried ".$search."

```
mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET m1 = '$M1', m2 = '$M2',m3 = '$M3',m4 = '$M4',m5 =    '$M5',m6 = '$M6',m7 = '$M7' WHERE $search = `student_id`");
?>
```

Table

+------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

|student_id|m1|m2|m3|m4|m5|m6|m7|

+------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

===Database d1

== Table structure for table grades

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**student_id**//|int(5)|No|
|m1|text|No|
|m2|text|No|
|m3|text|No|
|m4|text|No|
|m5|text|No|
|m6|text|No|
|m7|text|No|
== Dumping data for table grades

|11111| | | | | | | 
|11112|fg|fd|f|f|fd|f|f

===Database d1

== Table structure for table subjects

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**student_id**//|int(11)|No|
|c1|text|No|
|c2|text|No|
|c3|text|No|
|c4|text|No|
|c5|text|No|
|c6|text|No|
|c7|text|No|
== Dumping data for table subjects

|11111|English|Math|Science|Sport|IT|Art|History
|11112|grdgg|vsbvbbb|bdbbrfd|bdbrb|dbrbfbf|fbdfbdbf|dbfbdfb

Comment: what is the your column name? in WHERE $search = `student_id`"?

Comment: For debugging issues with SQL statements, it's helpful to assign the SQL text to a variable, e.g. $sql = "SELECT ... ", then output the contents of the string, before submitting the SQL text to the database.  (The PHP mysql interface is deprecated, new development should use either mysqli or PDO.)

Comment: see my edit it will solve your problem

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The values are not reflected into the input but instead in the **td**. Insert the row value into the input element so that you can $_POST the values.

```
$value = $row['m1'];

echo "<td><input type='text' name='m1' value='$value'></td>";
```

Comment: @JohnRobertson Its the solution to a problem I would have come across later down the path. But not the answer to the current one.


When I use a variable, the table gets updated with empty space, even if i have data in the input fields. It does update if i use numbers e.x. '11111' in the where condition.

Comment: @JohnRobertson
For example:
`mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET m1 = '$M1' WHERE `student_id` = '11111'");`

<----This updates the table,

``mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET m1 = '$M1' WHERE `student_id` = '$search'");

<----this doesn't

Comment: @ChristianCugnet make sure that $search is equal to a student_id in your table. Is it equal? like your student id is 10 then your search value is 10?

Comment: @JohnRobertson yes, I echo it just before the query and it matches the student_id

Comment: Whats strange, is that if I set the variable right before the update to 11111, it works.

Comment: @ChristianCugnet what are the datatypes in your table?

Comment: @JohnRobertson Do you mean text, int, varchar? If so then its 'int' for student_id and 'text' for m1

Comment: @ChristianCugnet is there anyway that you can edit your post and put your table and also the files associated with that code? so that we can solve it

Comment: @JohnRobertson best i can do is ascii... i need 10 reputation before i can post images

Comment: @JohnRobertson its the only table in use by the page. i add the code version of the table

Comment: @ChristianCugnet you should have two table since in your query you have subjects and grades selected. Do you have a subjects table and a grades table?

Comment: @JohnRobertson oh yeh, added

Comment: @ChristianCugnet so there are two records in your table right?

Comment: @JohnRobertson Yes, on for student_id "11111" and one for student_id "11112"

Comment: @ChristianCugnet that's why student '11111' can be change because his/her record is already existing. You need to add an "add record" so that you can add additional student and instead of update use "insert" to add record

Comment: @JohnRobertson I don't think its something to do with the tables. It's to do with the fact that the query only wants to use data from the $_POST array.

Comment: @ChristianCugnet there are only 2 records in the table so you can only search 2 records. 11111 and 11112. These are the records that you can update. If you will search 11113 ofcourse it will insert nothing in the table since your query is for updating not for inserting. Therefore, it will not update because no such record exists

Comment: @JohnRobertson I'm only trying to insert data into "11111"

Comment: @ChristianCugnet yes so it works because 1111 exists. So what's the other problem?

Comment: @JohnRobertson Only had one problem the whole time... The `mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET m1 = '$M1' WHERE student_id = $id");` clears the data unless I use a variable with data taken from $_POST or a variable set specifically `$id = 11111` in the WHERE condition. I can't use those 2 methods because I need $id to be the same as what the user entered into the search form.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE student_id='$search'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `grades` WHERE student_id='$search'");
```

Comment: as noted by spencer: With the equality comparison operation, the order of the expressions isn't important; 102 = foo is the same as foo = 102. (Granted, we are much more used to seeing predicates written as column = value, but it's just as valid to write it as value = column.